# NFS or SSHFS : How to disable client writes to server?

Tags: file, filesystems, mount, nfs, nfsclient

[EDIT] NFS or any other similar software like SSHFS.

1. client mounts from server
2. client modifies/writes contents of mounted FS

now i don't want to reflect those changes to the server. Is it possible?

Or is there any other FS. Thank you.

Comment: @nos Thanks, i edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you are looking for a distributed/networked FileSystem

1. you can mount on a Client
2. make changes to the FileSystem
3. do not report these changes back to the server hosting the FileSystem.

Why have a distributed FileSystem, then? This FS would need to track all changes for all users and isolate them against each other. I am not aware, that such an FS exists, and why would it, as I do not see the usecase for it.

Edit: If you want a working copy to mess around with/alter just *rsync* the directory from the server to your local machine. In case anything goes wrong, purge it and *rsync* again.

Comment: In my case the file system is huge is being used by a client application which needs to write data to run properly. Its not possible to rsync or replicate the data over all the clients because the data is huge. Any way?

Comment: In this case, why do you not split the data into a read-only part, and a write-part per client?

Comment: That was a cool hack and it works in my case, Thanks. But what if the clients application uses all files in write mode?

Comment: In that case you cannot share it between several clients any longer. This would most likely lead to race conditions and inconsistencies. Then, your only option is to have a dedicated read/write copy for that specific client. Or to reevaluate the process you are implementing.

Comment: Right, race conditions. Thanks @tobi.

Comment: Hmm, to quote Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition. And you're welcome :-)